# How to add alternating classes to dynamic feed of thumbnail images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, rss, frontend

I am bringing a feed of a youtube user's video channel onto a page via two plugins called jYoutube and jGFeed.

jGFeed: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jgfeed
jYoutube: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jyoutube

I am getting stuck on why this isn't working... I thought it would be as easy as a simple if/else statement, but it is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {     
            $.jGFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/POTATOwillEATyou/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile',
            function(feeds){
                // Check for errors
                if(!feeds){
                    // there was an error
                    return false;
                }
                var html = '';

                // do whatever you want with feeds here
                for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
                    var entry = feeds.entries[i];

                //My attempt at alternating classes:
                if((i%2) == 0)
                    {
                        console.log('hello')
                        $(".thethumb").addClass("even");
                    }
                else
                    {
                        console.log('NOPE')
                        $(".thethumb").addClass("odd");
                    }
                //End of my attempt

                   html += '<a rel="vidbox" class="thethumb" target="_blank" href="' + entry.link + '" title="' + entry.title + '"><img src="' + $.jYoutube(entry.link, 'small') + '" class="thumb left"></a>';
                }
                $('#you_tube_feed').html(html);
            }, 25);
        });
```

Comment: My outcome is alternating console logs saying hello and nope, but no classes added to .thethumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are are changing the class of ALL `.thethumb`, and they don't exist at the time you're running that code (they're inside your html string)

```
for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++)
{
    var entry = feeds.entries[i];

    var $new = $('<a rel="vidbox" class="thethumb" target="_blank" href="' + entry.link + '" title="' + entry.title + '"><img src="' + $.jYoutube(entry.link, 'small') + '" class="thumb left"></a>');

    if((i%2) == 0)
    {
        $new.addClass("even");
    }
    else
    {
        $new.addClass("odd");
    }

    $('#you_tube_feed').append($new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JQuery, it's even more simple . . . add all of the thumbnails first and then go back use the `:even` and `:odd` selectors to add the classes all at once:

```
$('.thethumb:even').addClass('odd');
$('.thethumb:odd').addClass('even');
```

You'll noticed that the classes are switched in comparison to the selectors . . . that is because the JQuery selector is 0-based, so items "0", "2", "4", etc. are actually the 1st, 2rd, 5th, etc. items in the selection.